# How to make union of nested array in lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have below array format and i want to make union of it using lodash or normal js.

```
var testArray = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[1,2,3,4,5,10,7,8],[1,2,3,6,7,8],[9],[3,4,5]]
```

I want to make union of all these into one and output should be below array.

```
testArray  = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Comment: please show some code on this

Comment: https://lodash.com/docs#union

Comment: You can [try this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29322081/3682162)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge two arrays in Javascript and de-duplicate items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yy0rLt8n/ Native way if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could combine [`flattenDeep`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#flattenDeep) with [`_.union`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#union). If needed apply sorting

```js
var testArray = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[1,2,3,4,5,10,7,8],[1,2,3,6,7,8],[9],[3,4,5]],
    result = _.chain(testArray)
             .flattenDeep()
             .union();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i dn't why OP want make a array  like `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` .but your answer like `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,9]` .why last two number was swap? is right or wrong?

Comment: @prasad, unique maintains the order of the items. if needed, then do a sorting afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Apply `_.union()` to the parent array:

```js
var testArray = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[1,2,3,4,5,10,7,8],[1,2,3,6,7,8],[9],[3,4,5]];

var result = _.union.apply(_, testArray);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Or use [array spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) if ES6 is supported:

```js
const testArray = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[1,2,3,4,5,10,7,8],[1,2,3,6,7,8],[9],[3,4,5]];

const result = _.union(...testArray);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

With ES6 you can do this using spread syntax `...` and `Set`

```js
var testArray = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[1,2,3,4,5,10,7,8],[1,2,3,6,7,8],[9],[3,4,5]]

var result = [...new Set([].concat(...testArray))];
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just call `_.union.apply(null, arrays)`. It is documented here:

https://lodash.com/docs/#union

```
> var testArray = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[1,2,3,4,5,10,7,8],[1,2,3,6,7,8],[9],[3,4,5]]
> lodash.union.apply(null, testArray)
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 9 ]
```

The apply trick is to transform your array of array in to function call arguments. If you need it sorted as well, you can just tuck `.sort()` at the end of it.

Answer (score 0):

In just ES5 if you need that:

```
var flattened = Object.keys(testArray.reduce(function(acc, cur) {
  cur.forEach(function(v) {acc[v] = true;});
  return acc;
}, {})).sort(function(a, b) {return a - b;});
```