# Union of 2 arrays using lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, lodash

I have the following 2 arrays:

```
    arr1 = [
            {
                "key1": "Value1"
            },
            {
                "key2": "Value2"
            },
            {
                "key3": "Test3"
            },
            {
                "key4": "Test4"
            },
            {
                "key5": "Test5"
            },
            {
                "key6": "Test6"
            },
            {
                "key7": "Test7"
            }
        ]
```

And the second array is

```
    arr2 = [
            {
                "key3": "Value3-changed"
            },
            {
                "key6": "Value6-changed"
            }

        ]
```

Now once I join the 2 arrays the result would be

```
   resultArr = [
        {
            "key1": "Value1"
        },
        {
            "key2": "Value2"
        },
        {
            "key3": "Value3-changed"
        },
        {
            "key4": "Test4"
        },
        {
            "key5": "Test5"
        },
        {
            "key6": "Value6-changed"
        },
        {
            "key7": "Test7"
        }
    ]
```

I saw the solution for [Lodash union of arrays of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29320817/lodash-union-of-arrays-of-objects). But as for my case, the keys are different. Any, pointers on solving this issue? I was trying to use lodash _.unionBy and then _.uniqWith but not getting the desired result.

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: Can you copy the code into a snippet so we can see where it might have gone wrong?

Comment: Why does this need to be an array?

Comment: Without lodash, you can concat 2 arrays, and the remove duplicates element if you need the union semantics. See for instance : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge two array of object by using lodash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38612972/how-to-merge-two-array-of-object-by-using-lodash)

Comment: also possible duplicate : [lodash - Union of arrays of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29320817/lodash-union-of-arrays-of-objects)

Answer (score 2):

No lodash needed. First reduce both arrays to a single object, where keys coming later overwrite any previously set values:

```
const obj = [...arr1, ...arr2].reduce((acc,cur) => Object.assign(acc, cur), {});
// {key1: value1, ...}
```

**Edit, even simpler:**

```
const obj = Object.assign({}, ...arr1, ...arr2);
```

Then map the keys back to an array of objects:

```
const resultArray = Object.keys(obj)
   .sort() // if alphanumeric order of keys matters to you
   .map(key => { const o={}; o[key]=obj[key]; return o;});
```

Comment: As i see it, they're supposed to be unique, ie. key3 in arr2 overwrites key3 in arr1, etc.

Comment: So 31piy what do you mean?

Comment: so to be clear, there will only be unique keys with this code. You saying there should be duplicates instead?

Comment: Looking at OP's example, you are correct, it seems there should not be duplicates, instead the values in second array should overwrite the values in the first array.

Comment: Yes, that's what's happening here. obj will only have one of each key. Object.assign({key3: 'old'}, {key3: 'new'}) ==> {key3: 'new'}

Comment: Actually, with more use of spread op. this could be written in an even simpler way. I'll edit

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without lodash like this :

(pushes new objects, or update existing one.

```js
let arr1 = [
    {
        "key1": "Value1"
    },
    {
        "key2": "Value2"
    },
    {
        "key3": "Test3"
    },
    {
        "key4": "Test4"
    },
    {
        "key5": "Test5"
    },
    {
        "key6": "Test6"
    },
    {
        "key7": "Test7"
    },
]

let arr2 = [
    {
        "key3": "Value3-changed"
    },
    {
        "key6": "Value6-changed"
    },
    {
        "key10": "Value10-new"
    },
]

for (let obj of arr2) {
    let keyName = Object.keys(obj)[0];
    let existingObject = arr1.find(x => Object.keys(x)[0] === keyName );
    
    if (existingObject) {
        // object with same key exists. So we update it.
        existingObject[keyName] = obj[keyName];
    } else {
        // key was not found, this is a new object, let's add it.
        arr1.push(obj);
    }
}

console.log(arr1)
```

There is probably a more elegant way to do that, of course.

Comment: Thanks @Pac0 for your help. I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the `...` spread operator:

```
map(chunk(toPairs(assign(...arr1, ...arr2))), fromPairs)
```

Otherwise:

```
map(chunk(toPairs(spread(assign)(concat(arr1, arr2)))), fromPairs)
```

Which is ugly but does the job.

---

#### Lodash plugins

```js
_.mixin({
  'assignPairsChunkAndMapObjects' : function(arr1, arr2) {
    return _.map(_.chunk(_.toPairs(_.assign(...arr1, ...arr2))), _.fromPairs);
  },
  'assignPairsChunkAndMapObjectsChained' : function(arr1, arr2) {
    return _.chain(_.assign(...arr1, ...arr2)).toPairs().chunk().map(_.fromPairs).value();
  }
});
```

Comment: But that creates a single object with all the keys. OP wants an array of each object in the original with updated key-value pairs.

Comment: I converted your code to a Lodash plugin and added a chained version which accomplishes the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

With native javascript you can achieve the same using `for ..in` & map function

```js
var arr1 = [{
    "key1": "Value1"
  },
  {
    "key2": "Value2"
  },
  {
    "key3": "Test3"
  },
  {
    "key4": "Test4"
  },
  {
    "key5": "Test5"
  },
  {
    "key6": "Test6"
  },
  {
    "key7": "Test7"
  }
]
var arr2 = [{
    "key3": "Value3-changed"
  },
  {
    "key6": "Value6-changed"
  }

];
// get object keys from both
var getArr2Keys = arr2.map(function(items) {
  for (let keys in items) {
    return keys;
  }
});

var getArr1Keys = arr1.map(function(items) {
  for (let keys in items) {
    return keys;
  }
});


// iterate over the newly created object and check if the key matched
getArr2Keys.forEach(function(itemArr2, index) {
  var x = getArr1Keys.findIndex(function(itemArr1) {
    return itemArr2 === itemArr1;
  })
  // replace the key value of arr1 with value from arr2
  arr1[x][itemArr2] = arr2[index][itemArr2]

})

console.log(arr1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mixin to iterate over the first array and merge it with the second one.

```js
_.mixin({
  'mergeObjectList' : function(arr1, arr2) {
    return _.map(arr1, function(obj) {
      Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
        var found = _.find(arr2, x => Object.keys(x).indexOf(key) > -1);
        if (found != null) {
          return _.merge(obj, found);
        }
      });
      return obj;
    });
  }
});

var arr1 = [
  { "key1": "Value1" },
  { "key2": "Value2" },
  { "key3": "Test3" },
  { "key4": "Test4" },
  { "key5": "Test5" },
  { "key6": "Test6" },
  { "key7": "Test7" }
];

var arr2 = [
  { "key3": "Value3-changed" },
  { "key6": "Value6-changed" }
];

var arr3 = _.mergeObjectList(arr1, arr2);

document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(arr3, null, 4);
```

```css
body { font-family: monospace; white-space: pre; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method of array.

> In ES5

```js
var arr1 = [{
    "key1": "Value1"
  }, {
    "key2": "Value2"
  }, {
    "key3": "Test3"
  }, {
    "key4": "Test4"
  }, {
    "key5": "Test5"
  }, {
    "key6": "Test6"
  }, {
    "key7": "Test7"
  }],

  arr2 = [{
    "key3": "Value3-changed"
  }, {
    "key6": "Value6-changed"
  }],

  key = '';

var result = arr1.map(function(item) {
  key = Object.keys(item)[0];
  return arr2.find(function(v) {
    return v[key]
  }) || item;
});

console.log(result);
```

> In ES6

```js
const arr1 = [{
    "key1": "Value1"
  }, {
    "key2": "Value2"
  }, {
    "key3": "Test3"
  }, {
    "key4": "Test4"
  }, {
    "key5": "Test5"
  }, {
    "key6": "Test6"
  }, {
    "key7": "Test7"
  }],

  arr2 = [{
      "key3": "Value3-changed"
    }, {
      "key6": "Value6-changed"
    }

  ];

let result = arr1.map(item => {
  let key = Object.keys(item)[0];
  return arr2.find(v => v[key]) || item;
});

console.log(result);
```